# Can you track an event in Google Analytics when the phone call is made, as opposed to just when the user clicks on the number?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, conversions, event-tracking, click-tracking

Here is how the flow on the website works:

1. There is a button called "show phone number"
2. Click the button and the phone number reveals "0850 XXX XXX"
3. Click the number and if you are on your mobile phone, "do you want
   to call 0850 XXX XXX" pop up window appears.
4. Click "Yes" and you call the number through your phone.

I am able to track the clicks on "flow 2" as a conversion event but I was wondering if:

- Is it possible in anyway to track the "actual" conversion as an event which happens in the "flow 4" or at least in the "flow 3".
  Our primary conversion is not the reveal button but the actual calls so we would like to optimize our campaigns by the actual calls and not by the reveal button clicks.
- If not, what is the roadblock? Any information regarding how the system works would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, and "flow 3" is still on the site, you can track it by throwing a gtag event when a user presses yes to the "do you want to call 0850 XXX XXX" prompt, and then, set the goal on google analytics to record a conversion once the event is sent. If there are problems with throwing ga events, I highly recommend using GTM (Google Tag Manager), which should make implementing this behavior pretty straight forward. Again, all of this is assuming that "flow 3" is still on site.

Good luck!

Comment: My guess is that the pop-up confirmation for "do you want to call" is part of the phone dialing app and is not part of the site.

Comment: I agree, it's much more likely that this is the case. If it is, my answer is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the answers,
I have also confirmed with internal team that the flow 3 and 4 does not happen in the website.
But the question remains, is there anyway to track either of them still? There must be a connection or trigger to track somehow.

Comment: I think the direction you should go for is something along the lines of the call tracking that Google Ads provides (Not necessarily use it, but a similar event), however, I have never done anything like it... Best of luck, and please do update on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think we will solve it in the long run -maybe in a year- eventually. I will update if we can make it.